# How to call specific function in a view which contains multiple plugins

Tags: joomla

As the title says, I'm considering about how to call a specific function of a plugin in a view.

For example, I have a view whose name is `myView`. And in this view, I import 2 plugins, they are 'plgx' and 'plgy'. Both of them have a function named `myFunction`.

Now I want to call `myFunction` function of these plugins but I don't know how to call them specifically.

Besides using different names, are there any other solutions for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Suppose your two plugins are loaded within the view then simply access with its class name like below.

```
if (!class_exists('vmPSPlugin')) require(JPATH_VM_PLUGINS . DS . 'vmpsplugin.php');
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('vmshipment');
ShipmentPluginClassName :: myFunction();
```

second Plugin like

```
if (!class_exists('vmPSPlugin')) require(JPATH_VM_PLUGINS . DS . 'vmpsplugin.php');
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('vmpayment');
PaymentPlugnClassName :: myFunction();
```

Hope this helps..